# How can I configure HTML Purifier to allow data URIs for image src?

Tags: php, rich-text-editor, htmlpurifier

How can I allow base64 data for the the src attribute of image tags? I see code like this:

```
$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array('http' => true, 'https' => true, 'mailto' => true, 'ftp' => true, 'nntp' => true, 'news' => true, 'data' => true));
```

In this case, is it `data => true` which allows the base64? And if so, how can I allow base64 data only for the src attribute of the img tag? (I do not want to allow data URIs in other situations.)

I thought of doing something like:

```
$ def-> addAttribute ('a', 'target', 'Enum # _blank, _self, _target, _top');
```

But in my case like this:

```
$ def-> addAtribute ('img', 'src', 'Enum # data, http, https, ...);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to only allow data URLs  for image SRC attribute? Or you want src attribute for images to always be data URLs?

Comment: "So you want to only allow data URLs for image SRC attribute?" Yes ;) I want to allow for image SRC attribute : data, http, https, ressources/img/photo1.png ... For cons, I just want to allow the base64, so the data for the src attribute of the image tag. I will not allow the data on other tags

Comment: So only src attribute on img elements are allowed to be data urls?

Comment: Yes ;) only src attribute on img elements are allowed to be data urls

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Easy: just only have `data` in your allowed schemes:

```
$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array('data' => true));
```

Comment: Thanks but this way the data (like base64) may be passed to any tag attributes? As the href attribute of the tag <a>. Can there be a security breach ?

Comment: Yes. We validate the contents of the data to make sure it's image data and has the right content-type, so it should be OK.

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang is there support for cid?